# Saddle point property proof, min max

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-writing, convex-analysis

The [max-min inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max%E2%80%93min_inequality) proof shows that for a function $f: Z \times W \to \mathbb{R}$, we can algebraicly show the following:

$$
\sup_{z\in Z} \inf_{w\in W} f(z,w) \leq \inf_{w\in W} \sup_{z\in Z} f(z,w)
$$

Can we use a similar method to prove the following:
$$
\sup_{z\in Z} \inf_{w\in W} f(z,w) = \inf_{w\in W} \sup_{z\in Z} f(z,w)
$$

if we know there exists a saddle point $(\tilde{z},\tilde{w})$, and that $f(\tilde{z},\tilde{w}) = \sup_{w \in W} f(\tilde{z},w) = \inf_{z\in Z} f(z,\tilde{w}) $

Comment: First, $z$ must belong to $Z$, not $W$. Second, did you mean that $f$ is convex-concave lower semicontinuous?

Comment: @cheyp thanks, fixed the typo. And yes.

Comment: Ah sorry, if you already know that a saddle point exists, then you don't need convexity-concavity assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to consider the max-min inequality in this form:
$$\sup_{w\in W}\inf_{z\in Z}f(z,w)\leq \inf_{z\in Z}\sup_{w\in W} f(z,w),$$
which is true because of the same arguments.

Next we have (omitting $Z$ and $W$ in $\inf$ and $\sup$)
\begin{align}
f(\tilde z, \tilde w) & = \inf_z f(z, \tilde w)\leq \sup_w \inf_z f(z,w)\\
f(\tilde z, \tilde w) & = \sup_w f(\tilde z,  w)\geq \inf_z \sup_w  f(z,w).
\end{align}
These two inequalities gives one the opposite inequality to the first one.

Comment: ahhh right. So they must be equal. great!

Comment: sorry opposite to which first one? not sure what you mean here

Comment: Opposite for the first one in my proof.

Comment: @cheyp I'm very curious, why do you say it's better to switch around the variables?

Comment: @Ovi Hm... not so sure now what I meant. Probably, it was "better" only for me for notation purposes. It is more common to have a problem like $\min_x \max_y f(x, y)$, where you do minimisation for the primal and maximisation for the dual variables. I just wanted to stick to that convention in my head.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply! I am also more used to the order you used.